# Follow user using TweetSharp 

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, exception, tweetsharp

I use following code to follow user:

```
TwitterService ts = new TwitterService(TWI_CONSUMER_KEY, TWI_CONSUMER_SECRET);
ts.AuthenticateWith(token.Token, token.Secret);

var users = ts.SearchForUser(query); //Get list of users by query
//...
foreach (var user in users) 
{
    var u = ts.FollowUser(user.Id); //Follow user
}
```

and get exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Item with the same key has already been added

Are there any mistakes? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The exception is being thrown as the user your adding, you're already following. You'll need to either:

1. Check if your already following that user, then follow
2. Wrap the `var u.ts.FollowerUser(..)` in a try/catch so the loop will continue

Comment: I have already wrap code with try\catch but remove this when post message. I get this error on each users in result list.

Comment: I download TweetSharp latest libraries and now code working ok. It's seems there was unfixed issue